# My code is not implementing correctly in a loop

Tags: c

Problem Statement

You love binary numbers 0 and 1. Now,You are given a binary string S of size N. Now you need to tell total how many 01 and 10 pair exist in the given string.

Note - A binary string is a string which contains only 0 and 1. And you have to consider 01 or 10 as consecutive.

Input Format

```
The first line will contain T, the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case contains a positive integer N.
The second line of each test case contains a string S, consisting only 0 and 1.
```

Constraints

```
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= 1000
```

Output Format

```
Print the count of pairs.
```

Sample Input 0

```
4
12
101011111010
6
101011
3
100
2
10
```

Sample Output 0

```
7
4
1
1
```

Explanation 0

> In the first case `101011111010`, there are 7 pairs. These are - `10 1011111010`, `1 01 011111010`, `10 10 11111010`, `101 01 1111010`, `10101111 10 10`, `101011111 01 0`, `1010111110 10`

Attempted Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int T,N,i,j,count=0;
    int S[100];

    scanf("%d",&T);

    for (i=0; i<T; i++){
        scanf("%d", &N);
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            scanf("%s",&S);
            if(S[j]=='0' && S[j+1]=='1'){
                count++;
            }
            else if(S[j]=='1' && S[j+1]=='0'){
                count++;
            }
            printf("%d", count);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things: `scanf("%s",&S);` should probably *not* be inside the loop. Secondly `S[j+1]` will be *out of bounds* for the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: 1. Check return values of `scanf` calls. 2. Add debug prints before (and maybe after) scanf calls, or use a debugger .

Comment: 3. When accessing `S[j]`, find a way make sure `j` is valid index, not beyond end of the string. Perhaps use `strlen(S)`...

Comment: Step 1: question the spec. Does `"010"` count as 1 pair (01) or 1 pair (10) or 2 pairs (01 10)? You can't be expected to read this between the line, it has to be written explicitly in the spec.

Comment: @cafce25 It's a bad spec if it can't be understood without an example.

Comment: In this case, as is common with "toy problems" the example is part of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Separate user I/O from the algorithm. Take all input first, then go through it afterwards.

As for the algorithm itself, it appears to be as trivial as this:

```
int count_pairs (const char* str)
{
  char prev = str[0];
  int count = 0;
  for(size_t i=1; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    if(str[i] != prev)
    {
      count++;
    }
    prev = str[i];
  }
  return count;
}
```

In your case you already have the string length so you can check `i<n` as well as checking for null termination.

Comment: But it's still not working